# Indicating the target of button define in class

Tags: python, class, tkinter, button

I am green in Python, after going through books and the questions here, I tried to code the following. The following is my simplified version of my code. this is a script for GUI. In my design, there would be a "back" button on the top, and 10 page buttons below it. And when I clicked the button, it will go to another page. But I replace it by showing the string of the picture instead.

However, I found that the "back" button is at the bottom now. I believe it goes wrong on Line 12.

I tried as "PageButton=ttk.Button(self, text=self.i, command=lambda: print(self.PicLink))" as well, but all page buttons disappeared. I am totally lost on what should be set to get back my designed pattern. Although it still work funtionally, I would like to know how should I edit to meet my orignial dseign, So I can improve my coding knowledge and problem solving skill. Thanks for all your effort in advance.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class PageButton(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, i, PicLink):
        self.i = i+1
        self.row=i//3+1
        self.column=i%3
        self.PicLink=PicLink
        super().__init__()
        print(self.i, self.row, self.column)
        PageButton=ttk.Button(text=self.i, command=lambda: print(self.PicLink))
        PageButton.grid(row=self.row, column=self.column)

class ViewerFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        ViewerFrame.backButton=ttk.Button(self, text="Back", command=lambda: BackPage(parent))
        ViewerFrame.backButton.grid(row=0, column=0)
        for i in range(10):
            PicLink="abc%04i.jpg" % (i+1)
            globals()['Button%s' % (i+1)]=PageButton(i, PicLink)

class ViewerPage(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Viewer")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        ViewerFrame(self).grid(sticky=(tk.E+tk.W+tk.N+tk.S))

def ViewerWindow():
    app=ViewerPage()
    app.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    ViewerWindow()
```

Comment: It is recommended to specify the *parent* of widgets, otherwise they are created as children of *root* window.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not specify the parent when creating the button inside `PageButton` class, it will be a child of the root window instead and put inside the root window instead of instance of `PageButton`.

Those *page buttons* are created and put into the root window before the instance of `ViewerPage` class which includes the `Back` button, so the `Back` button is being put after those page buttons.

So it is better to specify the parent when creating those page buttons and also `PageButton` should inherit from `ttk.Button` directly instead of creating an instance of it inside.

Below is the modified code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# inherit from ttk.Button directly
class PageButton(ttk.Button):
    # added parent argument
    def __init__(self, parent, i, PicLink):
        self.i = i+1
        self.row=i//3+1
        self.column=i%3
        self.PicLink=PicLink
        print(self.i, self.row, self.column)
        # specify the parent
        super().__init__(parent, text=self.i, command=lambda: print(self.PicLink))
        self.grid(row=self.row, column=self.column)

class ViewerFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.backButton=ttk.Button(self, text="Back", command=lambda: BackPage(parent))
        self.backButton.grid(row=0, column=0)
        # use a dictionary to store those page buttons
        self.buttons = {}
        for i in range(10):
            PicLink="abc%04i.jpg" % (i+1)
            self.buttons[f'Button{i+1}'] = PageButton(self, i, PicLink) # specify the parent

class ViewerPage(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Viewer")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        ViewerFrame(self).grid(sticky=(tk.E+tk.W+tk.N+tk.S))

def ViewerWindow():
    app=ViewerPage()
    app.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    ViewerWindow()
```